# Mystery domain being returned from Resolve Site Context

Tags: site-configuration

I get this kind of error in my logs.   I have changed the domain changed for company privacy, but...

The server's URL should be *dev.example.com*.   But somehow Sitecore is returning *www.exampledev.com*

This is not a domain that is owned by us.  I have reviewed the hosts file on the server, IIS bindings, etc.  I have used AstroGrep to search the entire Sitecore directory on the server.   I have used HeidiSQL to search all the Sitecore databases, and this domain appears nowhere in any of those locations.

Any ideas?

```
 416 11:51:22 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Site from host name and path was not found. Host: www.exampledev.com, path: /
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver.ResolveSiteContext(HttpRequestArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver.Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.(Object , EventArgs )
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I am using Sitecore 8.2 Update 2

Comment: Sounds like the DNS for `www.exampledev.com` is mapped to your server somehow... maybe try a reverse lookup on that domain to see if it is indeed pointing to your server. If this is locally, check you don't have a hosts file entry my accident.

Comment: It isn't our domain, and points to some other IP address.   If I run an nslookup on from the server or from my home machine, both come back with the same IP that isn't anywhere on our network.

Hosts file only has `127.0.0.1 Sitecore`

Comment: If you have a wildcard IIS binding to your web application, any request with a domain pointing to your server will be served by your web application.

Comment: I was initially seeing this domain appear when attempting to index content for Coveo.   The clickableUri had this weird domain in there, we got around that by setting the targetHostName attribute in the sitedefinition for all the sites.   Now Coveo index is correct, but I see the above error in the logs.   So it appears we band-aided it enough to make Coveo happy, but the root issue is still hanging out somewhere.

Comment: Did you check the serverUrl parameter in the Coveo Search Provider configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen things like this occur when another system hits Sitecore first with a domain name. It gets cached in as the resolving site since it is first used.

I would check for references of this domain in a health check system or another application installed on the server (sounds like you have Coveo there) to make sure something else isn't pinging Sitecore somehow with that domain. If it is setup on another server with a HOST entry to point at that box (such as a local dev instance pointed at the server IP address for testing) this would cause the problem.

On a side note, you didn't mention checking the ShowConfig.aspx page. Always worth looking there just to double-check some random include file isn't pulling it in.

Comment: Jason, nothing in the showconfig.aspx with that domain.   Currently have a ticket open with Sitecore Support now.